# How to get the name of the api gateway invoking aws lambda using java

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I'm trying to retrieve apigateway name in my Lambda code. I'v referred the following document on AWS http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html.

I understand that we can retrieve the API ID using the context variable. However I'm interested in retrieving the actual name of the API which was created. Is there any way of getting it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you can't get the API Gateway *name* directly, but you can get the API Gateway *Id*.

Both an event and context are passed in. In the event, there is a key called "requestContext". Inside the request context is the "apiId" key.

You could then use the API key id to look up the name if needed.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for ways to get the name in which the API was created. The API id looks like a unique alphanumeric string assigned by AWS. I would like to know how to get the name or is there any way to map the API id with the name? So that it's more readable.

Comment: you can use get_api_key() to get information of your ApiKey resource. See below link for example.
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.get_api_key

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will not be able to get API name directly from context, you will only get its identifier.

One way to get this information is to get your API information based on your ID from context:

```
response = client.get_rest_api(
    restApiId='string'
)
```

You will then receive this response:

```
{
    'id': 'string',
    'name': 'string',
    'description': 'string',
    'createdDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    'version': 'string',
    'warnings': [
        'string',
    ],
    'binaryMediaTypes': [
        'string',
    ],
    'minimumCompressionSize': 123,
    'apiKeySource': 'HEADER'|'AUTHORIZER',
    'endpointConfiguration': {
        'types': [
            'REGIONAL'|'EDGE'|'PRIVATE',
        ]
    },
    'policy': 'string'
}
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.get_rest_api